# can you make zsh autocorrect smarter?

Tags: zsh, line-editor, autocorrection

I like `zsh` autocorrect, but it keeps asking me about things that don't need correcting.

```
dzil build
zsh: correct 'build' to '.build' [nyae]? %
```

`.build` is a directory created by the `build` (or any other commands that run that action so `dzil .build` is always wrong, and `dzil build` is always right. Is there any way I can communicate this to the autocorrect system?

Comment: You may want to check out a solution proposed on StackOverflow: [zsh overzealously trying to correct feature to features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162322/zsh-overzealously-trying-to-correct-feature-to-features)

Answer (score 4):

Zsh's autocorrection only has limited configurability, but this should be enough for your use case. Set the [`CORRECT_IGNORE`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-CORRECT_005fIGNORE) variable to match the strings you want to ignore in autocorrection.

```
CORRECT_IGNORE='.build'
```

(I'm assuming you aren't using `correct_all`. With `correct_all`, I think being endlessly prompted about things that don't need correcting is unavoidable.)